# New thumbnail size url in WP returning "0" with Angular and WP-API

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress, wp-api

I'm working on a project using WP-API and Angular.

I just added a new custom image size to the **functions.php**

My **/wp-json/posts** (the JSON output) shows the url for the new image size and using the url works.

http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/6823214-large-600x300.jpg

But outputting the URL with Angular doesn't work (returns "0")

```
{{house.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.blog-thumb.url}}
```

However this still works fine (the original sizes):

```
{{house.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url}}
{{house.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.thumbnail.url}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have something to do with the "-" in the name (blog-thumb). I tried doing everything the same again using a new name (blogthumb) and everything worked fine!

Then just to make sure I added a new image size called "test-er" and had the same issues as the first time around.